# Windows: manually remove Start Menu current highlights

Tags: start-menu, highlighting

Not asking about how to disable the "Highlight newly installed programs" option. I'm looking for a way to keep this option enabled and instantly remove all *current* highlights, either one-by-one or preferably, all at once. Thanks for any ideas.

*disabling and re-enabling the option does not produce desired effect: all current highlights re-appear.